# Libreoffice Base - Triggering stock table deductions from orders table

Tags: sql, database, libreoffice, radix

I'm working on a DB that consists mostly of two tables. One with our stock of memorial markers, and the other where I keep a running list of ongoing and completed orders.

When I change an ongoing order in the Orders table to completed I would like to have one of the corresponding memorial markers deducted from that size category in the stock table.

I've mostly been building this using the form designer and wizards but I am comfortable with coding, though I'm not super familiar with SQL. Some pointers in the right direction should to get me going should help. I've been searching around but keep getting results for other things.

Thanks for your time

Comment: It sounds like this question is about database triggers, so it is important to specify the database engine — are you using PostgreSQL for example? LO Base is not the engine, but rather the front end. If you're using the built-in HSQLDB 1.8, you'll probably want to upgrade to something else in order to accomplish this task.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of a database trigger, perhaps you want the form to perform the change to the stock table. In that case, don't make a change directly to the orders table, but add a form input field, and then write code so that the form changes both the orders and the stock table.

Comment: This question is probably too open-ended for this site, where specific questions with a limited set of answers are expected. However, ask.libreoffice.org is less restrictive, so I recommend you post there instead.

Comment: Thanks Jim I will take this over to the other site, thanks for the suggestions and assistance.